# What is the meaning of 教训 here？

Tags: meaning

A very good fisherman taught his 3 sons his technique but he did not teach them 教训。 What does this 教训  mean here?

Earlier, in the text, it says:

> 可他三个儿子的捕鱼技术都很平庸。
>
> 别人告诉他：“你只传授给儿子们捕鱼的技术，却没有传授给他们教训。 没有教训与没有经验一样，都不能使人成功！”
>
> 教训：
>
> 1. 指从错误或挫折中得到的经验
> 2. 教育训练
> 3. 训导;训戒

I don't think this 教训 is 3. That leaves either 1 or 2.

The person said, "你只传授给儿子们捕鱼的技术", so the father taught them the technique. Maybe this 教训 here means 'training'? He taught them, but he did not train （训练） them?

Or 却没有传授给他们教训 means:

> but you did not teach them what you learned from your mistakes"

Answer (score 1):

It's 1, you might feel awkward or unfamiliar because:

When we take the meaning as 1,
we seldom says that someone teach others "教訓".

A more often way to use this meaning is to learn by someone itself.

Ex: 我從上次的失敗吸取教訓了，下次不會再犯同樣的錯。

I'v learned my mistake from last failure, and I won't make it again.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously 1.

I happen to Google the [source](https://books.google.com/books?id=Iu9nCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA72&lpg=PA72&dq=%E4%BD%A0%E5%8F%AA%E4%BC%A0%E6%8E%88%E7%BB%99%E5%84%BF%E5%AD%90%E4%BB%AC%E6%8D%95%E9%B1%BC%E7%9A%84%E6%8A%80%E6%9C%AF%EF%BC%8C%E5%8D%B4%E6%B2%A1%E6%9C%89%E4%BC%A0%E6%8E%88%E7%BB%99%E4%BB%96%E4%BB%AC%E6%95%99%E8%AE%AD&source=bl&ots=4tTApOVktx&sig=_A_uzxvZhTud0PJuZOAcFffKKZQ&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwie1ML4mOTWAhUMKyYKHY9QAQoQ6AEIMjAD#v=onepage&q=%E4%BD%A0%E5%8F%AA%E4%BC%A0%E6%8E%88%E7%BB%99%E5%84%BF%E5%AD%90%E4%BB%AC%E6%8D%95%E9%B1%BC%E7%9A%84%E6%8A%80%E6%9C%AF%EF%BC%8C%E5%8D%B4%E6%B2%A1%E6%9C%89%E4%BC%A0%E6%8E%88%E7%BB%99%E4%BB%96%E4%BB%AC%E6%95%99%E8%AE%AD&f=false).

Since the old man has taught his sons everything. 'Technique' is unlikely the answer.

And the whole context is about how to **deal with 'the failure'**. So it's 1.